# Return best match row across multiple independent fields in Python

Tags: python, arrays, lookup

I have a table with 5 independent fields & approx. 500,000 rows. All fields are numeric & floats, i.e. non-integers. Based on sample input data for each field, I need to return the row number of either an exact match or the best fit across all fields.

```
Sample data:
fldA,fldB,fldC,fldD,fldE
2.45,11.27,182.88,45.2,2.59

Table:
fldA,fldB,fldC,fldD,fldE
3.0672,19.31,49.7,113.2,5.0115
3.598,14.4591,242.7,193.2,3.502
1.259,7.14,135.2,93.97,4.097
2.35,11.91,187.63,37.6,1.5249
2.7635,9.49,201.03,79.1,13.8654

Desired output:
return row 4 (2.35,11.91,187.63,37.6,1.5249)
```

If I only needed exact matches I could to a nested 'if and' statement easy, but I'm struggling with the fact that I need the best match if no exact match exists, & that values can appear in the same field more than once, so I think all returns for each field need to be stored, then compared. But this wouldn't account for rows that are near matches, e.g. 0.01 of a difference.

I initially thought I could calculate the % difference between sample data & table, but this seems convoluted so thought there may be a simplier method.

Comment: Show some code?

Comment: You are going to have to come up with some measure of goodness of fit, or else the question will be too imprecise. One possibility would be something like a least-squares fit  but normalised by the variance of each column.

Comment: Calculating %error/difference for each column and selecting the row with lowest error seems to be a good way.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using this formula to get a best fit.

Let s_a = sample a, s_b = sample b, ... and s_i_a sample a for the i-th row of your table data. Then just search the minimum of:

[image]

You can do that by just looping over the rows, so per row you wil have 1 value. Store that value in an array together with its current row number, and then just compute the minimum of that array. Then return the corresponding row number.

Comment: The problem is that the different columns have very different ranges, so for example an error of (say) 1 in the first column should probably be considered as equivalent "badness" as a much bigger error in the third column, so you probably want to apply some kind of normalisation.